# Don't send anything back to AJAX function

Tags: php, ajax

A php file is being called via AJAX. Instead of sending anything back to AJAX function, I want to echo/print data to the HTML DOM from the PHP file. But anything that I would "echo" goes back to the AJAX function, even after removing the success function from AJAX request.

Comment: What you describe is exactly the normal behaviour of a webpage without AJAX which is used mainly to avoid that...

Comment: @Bartdude I am using AJAX to extract info from database without reloading the page. And that's why it becomes necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Since Ajax is the caller the echo Php will be return the result to the javascrpt.

You could return the php-path to the Ajax. Then load the php-path using the jquery load method.
OR
Return a json to the Ajax, and then create the html dynamically.